# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, windows-10

I have already ubuntu 20.04 installed on my lenovo laptop. How can I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10?

**EDIT**

Input: `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios`

Output: `efi`

Input: `sudo parted -l`

Output

```
Model: UMIS RPJTJ256MEE10WX (nvme)
Disk: /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sectore size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number Start   End   Size   File system   Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  538MB 537MB  fat32         EFI System Partition  boot, esp
2      538MB   256GB 256GB  ext4
```

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Windows is particular about drive partitioning as it only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drive and only in BIOS/CSM boot mode from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. If UEFI, it will share ESP. If BIOS, it has to have a primary NTFS formatted partition to boot from.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` and
`sudo parted -l`.  Post output from those commands into your question.

Comment: @PaulBenson I have modified my question

Comment: Easiest way to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, (once Ubuntu is installed ), is to buy Windows it's own SSD and remove the Ubuntu disk while you install Windows. on the new disk. If you want to boot Windows from Ubuntu's grub install it in the same BIOS/UEFI mode as Ubuntu. Installing Windows to the same disk Ubuntu is installed on is a hassle.

Comment: OK. You have 2 partitions with an ESP on sda1 and Ubuntu root on sda2. From Live Ubuntu you should back up both to an external drive at least 300 GB spare volume. You can do this using either Gparted or Disks. Root is probably occupying far less space than allocated. Shrink it down to a few GBs above current usage. So if just using 25 GB shrink sda2 down to 50 GBs before backing up. That gives you plenty of space to install Windows. Use another 60 GB for Win 10 and use rest of space as a partition for data, or better a separate disk for data..